# Complete list of LinkedIn skills

Tags: linkedin

Does anyone know if the complete list of skills used in LinkedIn.com can be exported, or downloaded?

I'm building a volunteer website and this would be handy to have.

Comment: AngelList might be a good alternative nowadays: https://angel.co/skills

Comment: http://www.free-db.com/data/4e86a521c22f5652026eba4fa79bc539_4_csv_download.csv

Comment: This has all that you want - http://tech.bragboy.com/2016/11/crawl-all-linkedin-skills.html

Answer (score 1):

There are probably tens of thousands of skills in the LinkedIn skill set, and there is no API to download this.  You can go to http://www.linkedin.com/skills/ and type in some skills that are relevant to the website or volunteering organization and you will get lists of related skills - you can probably pull together a pretty comprehensive list by following the chains of skills.

Answer (score 0):

> LinkedIn does not provide a list of the most popular LinkedIn skills & expertise. However using our LinkedIn expertise we pulled the 100 top LinkedIn skills as of November 5, 2012.
>
> We have published the most popular 15 skills with an excel spreadsheet with the entire list for free.

http://linkedinprofileservice.co/linkedin-profile/linkedin-profiles/linkedin-skills-list-top-linkedin-skills-examples/

Comment: The latest link with popular skills is located here: http://linkedinprofileservice.co/linkedin-profile-tips-advice/linkedin-skills-list/  If you have any further questions on linkedin skills email me. Happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

It is very simple. Go to your peers or role models in your field and review the skills they list. Then start entering those that you feel fit you the most. From this you will not only get a Best Practice list but one that fits those whom you admire the most.

This is not rocket science it is the art of people networking.